# UiModeManger not changing theme on Android 10

Tags: android, android-layout, android-10.0

When I try to change theme of system using Android UiModeManager on Android 10 nothings changing while it's working on Android versions less than 10. `

```
UiModemanger uiMode = (UiModemanger) getSystemService(Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE);
uiMode.setNightMode(UiModeManager.NIGHT_MODE_YES);
```

Its working on all Android versions except 10.

Answer (score -1):

According to Android docs:

> Note: On API 22 and below, changes to the night mode are only
>   effective when
>   the Configuration#UI_MODE_TYPE_CAR or Configuration#UI_MODE_TYPE_DESK mode
>   is enabled on a device. On API 23 through API 28, changes to night
>   mode are always effective.
>
> Starting in API 29, when the device is in car mode and this method is
>   called, night mode will change, but the new setting is not persisted
>   and the previously persisted setting will be restored when the device
>   exits car mode.
>
> Changes to night mode take effect globally and will result in a
>   configuration change (and potentially an Activity lifecycle event)
>   being applied to all running apps. Developers interested in an
>   app-local implementation of night mode should consider
>   using AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(int) to manage the -night
>   qualifier locally.

This method only works in Android 10 if car mode is enabled.

Comment: So should I also enable car mode in Android 10 for the night mode to work?

Comment: so is there any way to enable car mode without showing the notification

Comment: On Android 10 if device in car mode then setNightMode has same effect as not in car mode. The only difference between 23-28 and 29 is after exit car mode may be restored on api 29